# Nextjs - Contentful - Tags - Dynamic pages

Tags: graphql, tags, next.js, categories, contentful

I would like to create dynamic pages when I click a tag in an article or elsewhere on my website.

I'm using Next.js, SSG, and fetching the articles containing the tags from Contentful with the following GraphQL queries:

```js
export async function getArticles() {
  const articlesQuery = gql`
    {
      articleCollection(order: date_DESC) {
        items {
          title
          slug
          excerpt
          date
          contentfulMetadata {
            tags {
              name
              id
            }
          }
          featuredImage {
            title
            url
            width
            height
          }
          author {
            name
            photo {
              fileName
              url
              width
              height
            }
            title
            twitterProfile
            linkedInProfile
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
  return graphQLClient.request(articlesQuery);
}
```

```js
export async function getArticle(slug) {
  const articleQuery = gql`
    query getArticle($slug: String!) {
      articleCollection(limit: 1, where: { slug: $slug }) {
        items {
          title
          slug
          excerpt
          date
          contentfulMetadata {
            tags {
              name
              id
            }
          }
          featuredImage {
            title
            url
            width
            height
          }
          author {
            name
            photo {
              fileName
              url
              width
              height
            }
            title
            twitterProfile
            linkedInProfile
            slug
          }
          content {
            json
            links {
              entries {
                block {
                  sys {
                    id
                  }
                  __typename
                  ... on VideoEmbed {
                    title
                    embedUrl
                  }
                  ... on CodeBlock {
                    description
                    language
                    code
                  }
                }
              }
              assets {
                block {
                  sys {
                    id
                  }
                  url
                  title
                  width
                  height
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  return graphQLClient.request(articleQuery, {
    slug,
  });
}
```

The contentfulMetadata is where the tags come from:

```js
contentfulMetadata {
            tags {
              name
              id
            }
          }
```

This is my [id].jsx file:

```js
import { getArticles, getArticle } from "@utils/contentful";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await getArticles();

  return {
    paths: data.articleCollection.items.map((article) => ({
      params: { id: article.contentfulMetadata.tags[0].id },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const data = await getArticle(context.params.id);

  return {
    props: { article: data.articleCollection.items[0] },
  };
}

export default function TagPage({ article }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get the following error:
`` Error: Error serializing `.article` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/tags/[id]". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. ``

When `console.log(data.articleCollection.items.contentfulMetadata.tags.id);` or `console.log(data.articleCollection.items.contentfulMetadata.tags[0].id);` within getStaticPaths function it provides the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined`

Can anyone show how to create a dynamic page ([id].jsx) file, which shows the tag id as the header `<h1>` as well as all articles containing the same tag?

Comment: Maybe one of your `article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id` is undefined? Are you sure they are all there?

Comment: I'm not certain. From what I can get from the error message, I don't provide a string. I tried changing it to .name instead of .id, but no success.

Comment: Well, you can try `console.log` it there, for example. And see if some of them is undefined

Comment: It doesn't seem to log anything. Hm.

Comment: Well, this can't be true, add `console.log(data.articleCollection.items)` before `.map` call and then also log `id` inside map

Comment: That helped! Outside the ```.map```I get ```contentfulMetadata: { tags: [Array] },``` as well as title, slug and other fields. 

I'm not sure why it doesn't want me to do it inside the ```.map```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235280/discussion-between-mathias-riis-sorensen-and-danila).

Comment: @MathiasRiisSørensen did u solve this?

Comment: @diegoaguilar No, it's not solved yet. Do you have a suggestion? :)

Comment: From what I see ... it's weird hehe....

But I'd split a bit the code inside the map. That's gonna help.

Comment: ALSO, isn't tags an array? If so, tags.id won't work.

Then if tags is an array and u map again you'll need to flat.

AND finally it's always a good idea to filter to avoid nulls and empty arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here .

`article.contentfulMetadata.tags` is an array, as an entry can have more than one tag. So you'll need to access the tag you want via `article.contentfulMetadata.tags[0].id` or `article.contentfulMetadata.tags[desired_index].id` and so on.

Here's an example GraphQL query:

```
query {
  blogPostCollection {
    items {
      contentfulMetadata {
        tags {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

And here's the response with tags as an array:

```
  "data": {
    "blogPostCollection": {
      "items": [
        {
          "contentfulMetadata": {
            "tags": [
              {
                "id": "salmastag",
                "name": "Salma s tag"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "contentfulMetadata": {
            "tags": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how if a blog post doesn't have any PUBLIC tags assigned (the second entry in the response), an empty array is returned — you might want to do some safety checking in your code for this.

Comment: Thanks for letting me in the right direction! I still cannot get it to work. Can you show me how you would create the [slug].jsx file? I get an 404 error now.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without some console output. Here's an example of a [slug].js file — but it doesn't use tags. In fact, I'm not sure tags is the right way to go for generating slugs — perhaps a separate slug field on the blog post for this reason? (As the slugs will need to be unique?) https://github.com/whitep4nth3r/nextjs-contentful-blog-starter/blob/d80dc1e44a827bc3e6e30ca8c699a4b60f626040/pages/blog/%5Bslug%5D.js#L26

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I't hard to log, as I never get to the specific tag page as I'm getting a 404 page instead. 

Would you suggest to add another field within Contentful called tags and use that instead of contentfulMetaData?

Comment: I've changed the code to look for id, would you be able to run through the changes to see if we can get any closer to a resolution? It does give me an error now when I try to navigate to the tags page, which is better than the 404 page I had before.

Comment: Join the Contentful Community Slack @ https://www.contentful.com/slack and come and post your question in the help channel, and I'll find you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have posted it now :)

Comment: How to fetch all the tags separately from the content types? So only all tags.. Can't seem to find a way to do it via GraphQL